# Toyota Hiace 2-17 CPU to OBD2 issue

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, hiace

I have a 2017 Toyota Hiace which is a JDM version imported from Japan. I am trying to connect some extra gauges via OBD2 using a scanner tool such as ELM27 and Scangauge3. I also have a third tool and all of them fail to connect to the ECU. I am sure each scanner works so am just stuck with the communication issue and perhaps a correct protocol between CPU and scanner.
Any advice is appreciated.
Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!